# Call a method after 5 sec. without NSTimer

Tags: ios, objective-c

I want to call any method OR event after 5 second in iphone without using NStimer.

Answer (score 13):

Use *performSelector:withObject:afterDelay:* method.

```
[self performSelector:@selector(methodName) withObject:nil afterDelay:5];
```

Answer (score 9):

Or use GCD:

```
double delayInSeconds = 5.0;
dispatch_time_t popTime = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, (int64_t)(delayInSeconds * NSEC_PER_SEC));
dispatch_after(popTime, dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void){
    /* code to be executed on the main queue after delay */
});
```

Comment: +1 because this is how I use it as it allows for complex method calls with more than just one argument

Comment: how to stop calling this method in view will disappear ?

Answer (score 0):

The question sounds like a very pointless assignment. That calls for an equally useless answer:

```
sleep(5);
[self myMethodToCallAfter5Seconds];
```

**Edit:** Since people don't seem to like my answer, here are some thoughts:

The OP asked for a way to send a message after a delay. He explicitly asked for a way to do this without using an `NSTimer` yet he didn't specify why. As there are many ways to send a message after a delay, picking one depends upon the reason why to avoid any specific method. Not knowing the reason for refusing  an obvious approach there's only speculation.

One possible situation could be a background thread without a runloop that should await the delay. Here my (not totally serious) proposal could even be a proper solution when blocking the thread is not an issue. In this scenario neither `NSTimer` nor `performSelector:withObject:afterDelay:` could be used.

I added this answer to highlight the fact that the question makes little sense without giving a reason. As my answer fulfills the specification it shows the pointlessness of the question.

Comment: then why not `int t=time(NULL);while(time(NULL)<t+5);`?

Comment: @mvds I assume you're being sarcastic. Yet, also your example would point out the pointlessness of the question so, yes, why not?

Comment: I'm not here to judge questions (but if you are: use comments and votes for that), I'm here to help people out. We all started out knowing nothing and just trying stuff to see what works and what doesn't. Calling `sleep()` works, but is in some cases very bad practice (blocking main thread) and I wouldn't like to see the OP come back in a few weeks with a blocking main thread issue, especially if there are reasonable alternatives. Funny thing is, `sleep(5)` is the shortest "solution" so the OP might even consider using it, also because the GCD code looks downright scary to the novice.